# XAMPP - Unable to connect to TOMCAT, Apache, and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, apache, visual-studio-code, xampp, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to connect to MYSQL on VSC on port 3306.

This is my XAMPP Error Log

[image: XAMPP Error log]

and my Apache httpd.conf is set to

Listen 8080

Since I'm trying to connect to VSC, this is my settings.json

```
   {
        "sqltools.connections": [
            {
                "mysqlOptions": {
                    "authProtocol": "default"
                },
                "previewLimit": 50,
                "server": "localhost",
                "port": 3306,
                "askForPassword": true,
                "driver": "MySQL",
                "name": "db_username",
                "database": "db_username",
                "username": "db_username"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have downloaded many extensions on VSC, like mssql, SQLTools, SQLTools MYSQL/MariaDB
[image]

and I've also downloaded MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

My main goal is to somehow be able to do MySQL on VS Code 2019, but i don't know if i'm on the right path or what i should do.

Comment: You only need xampp if you want to do web development, otherwise you can install mysql standalone. As to why you get those error messages - we do not know, you need to look into the error logs.

Comment: @Shadow I have installed the MySQL Extensions, but for some reason, they still don't work. Check the post for my downloaded extensions

Answer (score 1):

To get MYSQL working press "config" in XAMPP change the port number for SMSQL from 3306 to 3307, then restart XAMPP

Comment: This is a guess. May work, but still a guess.

Comment: it's not a guess, the XAMPP console is stating that there is an application already using port 3306, hence why mysql won't start, read the screen shot posted in the original question

Comment: May be a blocked port is not sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It isn't a block port issue though, I've tried multiple different ports, and all doesn't work. Another funny thing I've realised is that only my root account is capable of connection, not any other account